# Can I say 'Now I let you go'?

Tags: grammar

Is it right to say:
Your love was unfaithful, now I let you go  ?
Should I always use the verb with 'ing' in the end after the adverb 'now'?

And also, can I say 'Now you face the world'?

Comment: 1) *Now, I let you go.* is fine. 2) No, it's not that 'ing' should follow when you use 'now' -"now you see, what I just said?" 3) You 'can' say arrogantly - "You successfully faced me, now you face the world".

Comment: 0) Her love was not unfaithful— **she** was unfaithful.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.
And also, can I say 'Now I feel so blue'?
Will it be right?

Comment: Sure, you can say, "Now I feel so blue." (It's grammatically correct.) However, to be honest, it will sound like you are quoting a song, or trying to compose a poem. Such verbiage and phrasing is rarely heard in day-to-day conversation. If you want to sound natural, say, "Now I feel sad," or, "Now I'm depressed."

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!
Yes, you are right, it's for the song, and I was not sure about it.
Thank you again so much!

Answer (score 2):

It's better when you say: *Your love was unfaithful; I'm letting you go now.*

It is not necessary to use a verb in its continuous form with *now*. You can find useful information regarding the usage of *now* [here.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/now)

*Now you must/should(or any appropriate modal) face the world*  is a better alternative.

Comment: No problem! My answer contained suggestions only. You can definitely stick to your own way of expressing them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question will depend on whether you wish to speak conversationally and idiomatically and in a matter-of-fact manner, or in a slightly formal manner with a tinge of melodrama:

CONVERSATIONAL/IDIOMATIC
**You were unfaithful, and now I'm letting you go.**

A TINGE OF MELODRAMA
**Your love was unfaithful, and now I let you go.**